# Создавать ли еще один Cell, или сдвинуть текущий Cell в зависимости от условия?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть система комментариев, так же возможно под комментарием "ответить" (написать другой комментарий)

У меня для списков комментариев есть 1 `Cell` для него создан класс (`CommentCell`), по его `identifire` я заполняю список комментариев в

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Для того чтобы пользователь мог добавить свой коммент под другим комментом, что посоветуете сделать? Пользоваться той же ячейкой? или создать отдельно ячейку, фишка в том что ячейка с ответом должна быть сдвинуто в право, как видно на скрине. 
Если оставить эту же ячейку и сдвигать ее вправо то у меня программно не получилось это реализовать, вот что я пытался сделать:

```
let margins = myTableView?.layoutMarginsGuide
cell.contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (margins?.leadingAnchor)!, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

это приводит к крашу.

```
Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x17447d6c0 "UITableViewCellContentView:0x1012e0af0.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x174661480 "UILayoutGuide:0x174195880'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.
```

Как посоветовали создал отдельно ячейку и все норм. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы сделал другую ячейку. Может это и кажется перегрузкой, но скажем в будущем Вы решите, что надо ответы показывать другим цветом, или другим шрифтом или еще что-то, у Вас появится в коде много лишней логики, проще просто поменять  данные в сториборде ячейке и все заработает без лишних действий.

Comment: Комментарии только одного уровня, комментировать коментарии не нужно? Если так, сделайте 2 разных, тем более, что на срине некоторые отличия есть. Плюс можете по-разному катсомизировать потом их

Comment: @VAndrJ  есть комментарий под записью, (общий комментарий), а есть комментарий под другим комментарием(когда мы под основным комментарием тапнем "Ответить"). Пока что они идентичны, и между основными комментариями и под комментариями отличий нет ни каких за исключение что под комментарий будет сдвинут в правую сторону, как на скрине.

Comment: @VitaliEller спасибо, учту. В Парсинге в списке комментариев будет параметр child(массив), так вот этот child и будет подКомпментариями, его и нужно заполнить во вторую ячейку.

Comment: не надо добавлять ничего в заголовок вопроса - надо принять существующий ответ или добавить свое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!
Если в классе ячейки привязать левый constrant к IBOutlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftConstrant: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

То в layoutSubview можно менять constant в ограничении.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    leftConstrant.constant = CGFloat(self.indentationLevel) * self.indentationWidth 
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

indentationLevel можно менять в tableView (...cellForRowAt indexPath).